# CSS Doesn't Style Bottom Div But Does Top One

Tags: html, css, styles

I used this footer on my homepage and it worked fine, but copy and pasting it over to another webpage completely destroyed all the styling it had, which is weird, because the header (which I also copied from the same page) is completely fine and unchanged. Any thoughts? Here's a fiddle with all the code:

Okay, so I just put it into the fiddle and it worked fine, but it still doesn't work like it should when I open it in Chrome through Sublime Text.

Here's all the code:

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="navbar">
            <a href="index.html"><p class="navwords nonactive">Home</p></a>
            <a href="ourteam.html"><p class="navwords active">Our Team</p></a>
            <a href="weddings.html"><p class="navwords nonactive">Weddings</p></a>
            <a href="events.html"><p class="navwords nonactive">Events</p></a>
            <a href="contact.html"><p class="navwords nonactive">Contact</p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="headerlogo">
            <a src="#"><img id="background" src="assets/BlurryFlowers.png"></a>
            <a href="index.html"><img id="logo" src="assets/Logo.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ourteam">
        <div class="employee" id="brax">
            <h2>Brax</h2>
            <img src="assets/Braxpic.png">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vitae arcu quis risus elementum auctor in eu erat. Nullam sodales pulvinar eros, semper euismod elit pretium sit amet. Vestibulum vestibulum libero id ipsum viverra, condimentum vulputate urna volutpat. In lobortis sit amet risus id vehicula. Praesent in risus at urna mollis eleifend vel et arcu. Quisque urna leo, porta non turpis sit amet, gravida sagittis erat. Curabitur eu convallis purus. Vestibulum feugiat purus ac urna aliquet rutrum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="employee" id="ryan">
            <h2>Ryan</h2>
            <img src="assets/Ryanpic.png">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vitae arcu quis risus elementum auctor in eu erat. Nullam sodales pulvinar eros, semper euismod elit pretium sit amet. Vestibulum vestibulum libero id ipsum viverra, condimentum vulputate urna volutpat. In lobortis sit amet risus id vehicula. Praesent in risus at urna mollis eleifend vel et arcu. Quisque urna leo, porta non turpis sit amet, gravida sagittis erat. Curabitur eu convallis purus. Vestibulum feugiat purus ac urna aliquet rutrum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="favicon">
            <a href="index.html"><img id="favicon" src="assets/favicon.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="footernav">
            <a href="index.html"><p>Home</p></a>
            <a href="ourteam.html"><p>Our Team</p></a>
            <a href="weddings.html"><p>Weddings</p></a>
            <a href="events.html"><p>Events</p></a>
            <a href="contact.html"><p>Contact</p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="socialmedia">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/yourstorybookmemory/"><img class="social" src="assets/facebook.png"></a>
            <a class="socialText" href="https://www.facebook.com/yourstorybookmemory/"><p>Storybook Memories</p></a><br/>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/yourstorybookmemory/"><img class="social" src="assets/instagram.png"></a>
            <a class="socialText" href="https://www.instagram.com/yourstorybookmemory/"><p>yourstorybookmemory</p></a><br/>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/sbvideography"><img class="social" src="assets/twitter.png"></a>
            <a class="socialText" href="https://twitter.com/sbvideography"><p>@sbvideography</p></a><br/>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcMVbKyDIJN0Ht-6VjDiFKA"><img class="social" src="assets/youtube.png"></a>
            <a class="socialText" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcMVbKyDIJN0Ht-6VjDiFKA"><p>Storybook Memories</p></a><br/>
            <a href="mailto:inquiries@yourstorybookmemory.com"><img class="social" src="assets/mail.png"></a>
            <a class="socialText" href="mailto:inquiries@yourstorybookmemory.com"><p>inquiries@yourstorybookmemory.com</p></a><br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
/* PAGE SETUP */

*{
    font-weight: 100;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Lato', 'sans-serif';
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

/* HEADER FOR ALL PAGES */

.header {
    width: 100%;
}

.headerlogo {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#background {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}

#logo {
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(96,150,38,0.4);
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    height: 55px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}

.nonactive {
    color: white;
}

.active {
    color: black;
    cursor: ;
}

.navwords {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 1em;
    transition: .3s color;
    font-weight: 300;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.navwords:hover {
    color: black;
}

/* OUR TEAM SECION */



/* FOOTER SECTION */

.footer {
    background-color: #5c0e13;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.favicon, .footernav, .socialmedia {
    float: left;
}

.favicon {
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
}

.footernav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    transition: .3s color;
}

.footernav a:hover {
    color: #db1421;
}

.socialmedia {
    margin-left: 50%;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(10%);
}

.socialmedia p {
    margin: 6px;
    padding: 0;
}

.social {
    width: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.socialmedia a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    transition: .3s color;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.socialmedia a:hover {
    color: #db1421;
}

.socialText{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of what it's doing right now:

[image]

And here is a fiddle with an example of it working (sort of, that maroon background means it's working, because that's not working on the screenshot).

https://jsfiddle.net/f26w8boe/

Comment: where you getting distroyed..and please add a screenshot if u can

Comment: Can you provide a (working) demo of what goes wrong? If a snippet or a fiddle won't work, then links to the two differently rendering webpages, so we can compare.

Comment: Maybe you made a typo in the `<head>` of the page you copied to? Can you post that as well and/or specify what "completely destroyed all the styling it had" means?

Comment: @Jasiralwafaa Here is a link to the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f26w8boe/

Comment: @MrLister But the problem is that is just doesn't style. The link above is all my HTML and CSS.